# Convert headers and row level data to column level

Tags: vba, excel

I have very little experience working with VBA, so I'm having a hard time looking up what I am trying to do because I am having a hard time putting what I am trying to do into words.
I have been struggling to write a code to do the below task for the past few days.

Basically what I am trying to do is to convert a set of data to different format.

***This what my source data looks like.
Data:***
[image]

***and I need it to look like this
FinalLook:***
[image]

I've a already setup a code which is lengthy and incomplete.

FIRST PART

I started with retrieving a part of a data (`AQ:BA`) and then convert to the format in sheet2 with the below code.

```
Sub FirstPart()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Laaastrow As Long


   Sheets("sheet2").Range("a2:A5000").ClearContents

    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c5:c" & lastRow).Value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("b2:l" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("aq5:ba" & lastRow).Value


End Sub
```

But.. the problem i am facing with this code is that it pulls all the data, i do not want it to pull all the values, but only the ones which is not empty or 0. In other words, if AQ6:BA6 is empty, script should skip this particular row and go the next one.

SECOND PART (converting the sheet2 data to the final format)

```
Sub NormalizeSheet()
Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet4 As Worksheet
Dim strKey As String
Dim clnHeader As Collection
Dim lngColumnCounter As Long
Dim lngRowCounterSheet2 As Long
Dim lngRowCounterSheet4 As Long
Dim rngCurrent As Range
Dim varColumn As Variant

Set wsSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsSheet4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
Set clnHeader = New Collection

wsSheet4.Range("c2:c5000").ClearContents
wsSheet4.Range("e2:e5000").ClearContents
wsSheet4.Range("g2:g5000").ClearContents



lngColumnCounter = 2
lngRowCounterSheet2 = 1
Set rngCurrent = wsSheet2.Cells(lngRowCounterSheet2, lngColumnCounter)


Do Until IsEmpty(rngCurrent.Value)
    clnHeader.Add rngCurrent.Value, CStr(lngColumnCounter)
    lngColumnCounter = lngColumnCounter + 1
    Set rngCurrent = wsSheet2.Cells(lngRowCounterSheet2, lngColumnCounter)
Loop


lngRowCounterSheet2 = 2
lngRowCounterSheet4 = 1
lngColumnCounter = 1

Do While Not IsEmpty(wsSheet2.Cells(lngRowCounterSheet2, lngColumnCounter))

    Set rngCurrent = wsSheet2.Cells(lngRowCounterSheet2, lngColumnCounter)
    strKey = rngCurrent.Value
    lngColumnCounter = 2

    Do While Not IsEmpty(wsSheet2.Cells(lngRowCounterSheet2, lngColumnCounter))
        Set rngCurrent = wsSheet2.Cells(lngRowCounterSheet2, lngColumnCounter)


        If rngCurrent.Value = "NULL" Then

        Else

            wsSheet4.Range("c" & lngRowCounterSheet4).Offset(1, 0).Value = strKey
            wsSheet4.Range("e" & lngRowCounterSheet4).Offset(1, 0).Value = clnHeader(CStr(lngColumnCounter))
            wsSheet4.Range("g" & lngRowCounterSheet4).Offset(1, 0).Value = rngCurrent.Value
            lngRowCounterSheet4 = lngRowCounterSheet4 + 1
        End If

        lngColumnCounter = lngColumnCounter + 1
    Loop
    lngRowCounterSheet2 = lngRowCounterSheet2 + 1
    lngColumnCounter = 1
Loop



End Sub
```

I got this code from another thread posted here on stakcoverflow, i modified a bit to get this work.

The problem i am encountering here is that if `Sheet2 B2` is empty, the codes doesnt check `sheet C2` instead it skips the whole row, which is not right here.

I know this sounds complicated, and this approach of mine may not be even feasible.

Is there ANY OTHER WAY to do this? Is there any other way to get this in a single shot instead of breaking down the data and move each set of columns to `sheet2` then to final format?

Comment: You are going to have difficulties if your headings in row 3 span varying numbers of columns. I don't understand your problem as the column variable appears to go up by one if a cell is empty (the code does look as if it could be simplified though).

Comment: I understand that this not very easy to comprehend or may be this approach of using two set of scripts to perform a single task is not right. Do you know any other way to work around this?

Comment: Essentially all you're doing is looping through each row and looping through each column, and if the cell is not empty extracting a few bits of info to put in a table. There are some complications but that is it in essence.

Comment: Btw I see now you're earlier problem which is that your Do loop stops as soon as a cell is empty whereas I think you want it to carry on each row for a fixed number of columns. You could use a For-Next loop instead.

Comment: Or use SpecialCells to cycle through the values and you needn't worry about the blanks.

Comment: Could you please help me to correct my first code?

But then if i am following this method, i will have to breakdown each set of columns `( (AQ:BA),(BB:BK),(BL:BU) ...(ED:EM) )`to a new sheet with the help of this script  and then combine and convert to final format using the second script? Is there no simpler way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to break it down into those two stages. The outlined approach above does what you need - it's two loops.

Comment: May be i don't have to, but if i am using the first script i will have to break it down, as you can see in this first picture, Columns ( (AQ:BA),(BB:BK),(BL:BU) ...(ED:EM) ) has different main column header.
In the end i need it in the final format, does not matter which method i follow.

Comment: Are the cells in row 3 merged?

Comment: yes.
but for sake for getting this done i can rename the Cells AQ1:EM1 to merged cells value.

Comment: OK, that helps. And do you have data in the columns between B and AQ?

Comment: yes i do have some data between B and AQ

Comment: I've added an outline solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how you get on with this. You'll have to adjust range references, and possibly sheet names

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, c As Range

With Sheet1
    For r = 5 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(r, "AQ"), .Cells(r, "BK")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If c.Value > 0 Then
                Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Range("B1").Value
                Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 1).Value
                Sheet2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 2).Value
                Sheet2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(3, c.Column).Value
                Sheet2.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(4, c.Column).Value
                Sheet2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = "(blank)"
                Sheet2.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = c.Value
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End With

Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(, 7) = Array("TOPHEADER", "HEADER1", "HEADER2", "FROM", "TO", "TYPE", "UNIT")

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and effort!
it loads all the values and seems to work fine, but it fails to load values to `Shee2 tColumn D` (FROM header), it is loading value from (BV3:CE3) merged cell to `sheet2 D2, and neglects the other headers.

Comment: Ok I had assumed you were going unmerge those cells and repeat the headings in each cell? If that's not possible, will have to adjust the code.